# customising Job and job table in Laravel queue/ rename jobs table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

When I try `php artisan queue:table`
It gave me the following error

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                   
  A CreateJobsTable migration already exists.
```

It is because I have already the migration named `CreateJobsTable` for other purpose. I cannot rename this table and migration . Is there any way to rename the migration to `CreateJobsQueueTable` or some thing relevant?

**can we rename the jobs table that artisan creates with 'queue:table'?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes. Edit this file `config\queue.php`:

```
<?php

return [

    ....

    'connections' => [

        ....

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',      <------ Edit this to something else
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        ....
    ],

    ....
];
```

Change the `table` name to other value, and it should pick up by the `TableCommand`. Check out `Illuminate\Queue\Console\TableCommand` on how it uses this value. It's pretty much straightforward :)

Comment: I have no idea what the difference is but no matter what I try the 'table' property from the config does not stop it from going the 'jobs' table.

Comment: Which config file you are changing? You probably have a queue.php under config and edited the default queue.php from the framework. You should edit the one in app/config itself.