# Laravel queue/ rename jobs table

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I am using Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.2.5). My requirement is to change jobs table name ( instead of jobs, I want uat_jobs in UAT and prod_jobs in PROD).

So as suggested in [other StackOverflow anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294337/customising-job-and-job-table-in-laravel-queue-rename-jobs-table), changed table name in config\queue.php file but unable to create new job table.
Getting [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4D0O.png) while runing **php artisan queue:table** command.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically change job table name use

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        if ('PROD' == $this->app->environment()) {
            Config::set('queue.connections.database.table', 'prod_jobs');
        } else if ('UAT' == $this->app->environment()) {
            Config::set('queue.connections.database.table', 'uat_jobs');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lumen doesn't have the `queue:table` command - that's for Laravel. You'll want to create the jobs table migration(s) manually. From the docs:

```
Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('queue');
    $table->longText('payload');
    $table->tinyInteger('attempts')->unsigned();
    $table->tinyInteger('reserved')->unsigned();
    $table->unsignedInteger('reserved_at')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('available_at');
    $table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
    $table->index(['queue', 'reserved', 'reserved_at']);
});
```

Remember to rename the table in the above code to what you want.

Docs for your version: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues - if you are not used to queues in Lumen, you'll want to read the rest in there as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have created the table manually with jobs schema So I have not tried your solution.